# Invalid Next control variable reference ERROR

Tags: vba, loops

Im writing a code but i get the Invalid Next control variable reference error, and i don't know why. this is my code:

```
Sub Network()

Dim Net(1 To 8) As Double
Dim Total(1 To 8) As Double
Dim i As Integer


For i = 1 To 8
    For j = 1 To 5

        Net(j) = Worksheets("Summary").Cells((i * 7) + 12, 9).Value

    Next i
Next j



For j = 1 To 5

    Total(j) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Net(j))

Next j

For j = 1 To 5

    Worksheets("Summary").Cells(73, 8 + j) = Total(j)

Next j


End Sub
```

hope someone can help me get this error fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your i and j variables are the wrong way round, you need to make sure the correct variable is with the correct indentation.  Hope this helps!

```
Sub Network()

Dim Net(1 To 8) As Double
Dim Total(1 To 8) As Double
Dim i As Integer


For i = 1 To 8
    For j = 1 To 5

        Net(j) = Worksheets("Summary").Cells((i * 7) + 12, 9).Value

    Next j
Next i



For j = 1 To 5

    Total(j) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Net(j))

Next j

For j = 1 To 5

    Worksheets("Summary").Cells(73, 8 + j) = Total(j)

Next j


End Sub
```